# Kaltura embedded iframe player error on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, html5-video, kaltura

I'm trying to embed a video from Kaltura Video Platform in a HTML5 page.

I followed [the docs](http://knowledge.kaltura.com/embedding-kaltura-media-players-your-site) at Kaltura. So far I'm able to play the video in Safari, Chrome and Internet Explorer but it fails to load in Firefox. The firebug console shows this javascript error:

> ReferenceError: kWidget is not defined

The HTML5 code demostrating the issue follows (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELjbw/1) for a live demo):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="iframe_-1" src="http://www.kaltura.com/p/403921/sp/40392100/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/4438451/partner_id/403921?iframeembed=true&amp;playerId=iframe_-1&entry_id=1_40ttmxyq" width="400" height="330" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozAllowFullScreen frameborder="0">
        <a href="http://corp.kaltura.com/products/video-platform-features">Video Platform</a>
        <a href="http://corp.kaltura.com/Products/Features/Video-Management">Video Management</a> 
        <a href="http://corp.kaltura.com/Video-Solutions">Video Solutions</a>
        <a href="http://corp.kaltura.com/Products/Features/Video-Player">Video Player</a>
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

What puzzles me is that only Firefox is complaining. Has anybody experienced the same issue? Is some sort of cross-domain issue?

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of mwEmbed had a bug with the iframe embed ( 1.7.1.11 ) .

Please try upgrading to the [latest stable release](http://html5video.org/wiki/Kaltura_HTML5_Release_Notes#1.8.8) ( [1.8.7](http://cdnapi.kaltura.com/html5/html5lib/v1.8.7/mwEmbedLoader.php) ). Here is a [sample test page](http://player.kaltura.com/modules/KalturaSupport/tests/IframeEmbedFancyBox.html) working in firefox with that version.

Note the test page is doing something a lite different ( invocation via lightbox ), but the basic point is if you [update that uiConf](http://html5video.org/wiki/Kaltura_SaaS_FAQ#Controlling_the_HTML5_library_version_for_.com_uiConf_urls) to 1.8.7 everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks @mdale, I managed to workaround the issue by browser detection, but I don't like my solution. I will try to upgrade and accept the answer ASAP (a few days, I expect). Thanks a lot!